# Angular material md-tab conditional move on md-on-deselect response

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make wizard using md tab.How can i make the conditional move of the tab?.Ex- I want to call a service on tab change, tab should be change only when we get the success response. I have user md-on-deselect attr for that but tab moves before getting the response.

```
   <md-tab label="1. Details" md-on-deselect="CampaignCtl.test()">
        <md-content class="tabsContent">
            <div data-ng-include=" 'app/view/advertiser/campaigns/campaigns-detail.html'"></div>
        </md-content>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab label="2. Advertisement Media" md-on-deselect="CampaignCtl.test()">
        <md-content class="tabsContent">
            <div data-ng-include=" 'app/view/advertiser/campaigns/campain-advertiser-media.html'"></div>
        </md-content>
    </md-tab>
```

I am trying to call a service from test method

Comment: How you are deselecting the current tab?

Comment: there is attr in md tabs md-on-deselect

Comment: when you click on another tab then the selected tab will be deselected and function will fire?

Comment: i want to call function before deselect the tab. if function return success then tab should move